# What are some techniques for storing and reusing authorization tokens for scripts?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have a Python script that consumes data from an API. I run this script on my local machine and on a server. I authenticate using client credentials (client ID and secret key), receive an authorization token, and execute my requests. Once I am done, this token is still valid for quite a while longer. If I need to run this script again before the token expires, I would like to reuse the token instead of requesting another one.

I'm struggling to think of a way to store the token. How can I securely store this data for reuse?

This isn't a long running application, so the storage mechanism must be external to the script. Storing in a JSON file doesn't seem safe.

Comment: "Storing in a JSON file doesn't seem safe." Why? Unless your local host is compromised in the first place why would storing auth tokens in a file be unsafe? It is no less safe than your browser storing auth tokens as cookies in a local file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to a json file you could save the information in an environment variable. Nevertheless the implications regarding security would be the same. Other processes could use this environment variable as well.

Another option could be using encrypted files with. See two options below.

## cryptography

With [cryptography's Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet) you can create a key and encrypt information. This information can be written to a file.

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# generate key (needs to be stored as well!)
key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

# encrypt secret
token = f.encrypt(b"super secret")

# write secret to file
with open("secret.txt", "wb") as secret_file:
    secret_file.write(token)

# read secret from file and decrypt
with open("secret.txt", "rb") as secret_file:
    encrypted = secret_file.read()
    print(f.decrypt(encrypted))
```

## Ansible Vault

Another option could be [Ansible Vault](https://github.com/tomoh1r/ansible-vault). Please be aware that you still need to manage a password. **CAUTION!** This is not an official Ansible package. For more information on Ansible Vault see the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/vault.html) and the [github Repo](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel).

1. Save token to vault

```py
from ansible_vault import Vault
from getpass import getpass

token = "foo"

password = getpass()
vault = Vault(password)
vault.dump(token, open("vault.yml", "w"))
```

2. Read token from vault

```py
from ansible_vault import Vault
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass()
vault = Vault(password)
token = vault.load(open('vault.yml').read())

# check with pyjwt whether token is still valid...
# do more stuff
```